# django - how do I join the results of multiple models having foreign key the same user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have multiple models that point to the same user like this:

```
class Model1(moldels.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     title = models.CharField()
     ...

class Model2(moldels.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     ...

class Model3(moldels.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     ...
```

What to be able to do a search/filter on `title` field on `Model1` and join the results from the other models that have the same user. Only Moldel1 will return multiple results for the same user. Model2 and Model3 will always return one result for every user (like one avatar and one profile). - Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "join". You can access one from any other though `user` and the `related_name` of the model (by default: `<lowercase class name>_set`), e.g.:

```
model1_instance.user.model2_set.all()
```

Or you can use the user instance to access each directly:

```
user.model1_set.all()
user.model2_set.all()
user.model3_set.all()
```

You can query those models through the user as well, with query traversals:

```
User.objects.filter(model1__title='some title')
```

Finally, for the models that have only one instance, such as one profile per user, you should really be using `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey`. If you do that, then you can use `select_related` on any reverse relation that is a `OneToOneField` (true SQL JOIN), e.g.:

```
User.objects.filter(model1__title='some title').select_related('model2', 'model3')
```

However, `select_related` will *not* work on reverse foreign key relationship or many-to-many relationships. For that, you'll have to wait until Django 1.4 drops with `prefetch_related`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want get a queryset, this is impossible. You cannot get a queryset of various models.

But I think that you want something like this:

```
objs1 = Model.objects.filter(title__icontains='YOUR FILTER')
users = objs1.values('user').distinct()
objs2 = Model2.objects.filter(user__in=users)
objs3 = Model3.objects.filter(user__in=users)

objs = list(objs1)
objs.extend(list(objs2))
objs.extend(list(objs3))
return objs
```